# Construct object, set fields, and return object in a generic way in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following pattern nearly a thousand times in my codebase.

```
Foo *foo = new Foo();
foo->greeting = "Hello";
foo->legs = 4;

Bar *bar = new Bar();
bar->firstName = "John";
bar->lastName = "Smith";
bar->height = 5.6;
```

I would like to make this less verbose using a syntax like the following.

```
Foo *foo = construct<Foo, greeting, legs>("Hello", 4);
Bar *bar = construct<Bar, firstName, lastName, height>("John", "Smith", 5.6);
```

I would like to avoid using actual C++ constructors because writing `Foo(std::string greeting, int legs) : greeting(greeting), legs(legs) {}` for every class is lots of effort, is redundant, and is a mess when the class hierarchy is very tall and superclasses need to be called.
I imagine this might be possible with a template function or a macro, but I can't figure it out. What's the closest that can be achieved?

I should point out that C# has this unique feature build-in.

```
Foo *foo = new Foo{greeting = "Hello", legs = 4};
```

### Intention

Here is a small sample of my class hierarchy. In reality it contains 30 times more classes which many more fields and methods. I *do* use constructors, but I never use constructors with arguments, since it is expected that the caller construct it with default fields and set what they need after construction. Otherwise constructors would have 50+ arguments, and the caller would have to specify all the default values explicitly.

```
struct Widget {
    Vec pos = Vec(0, 0);
    Vec size = Vec(0, 0);
    float zoom = 1.0;
};

struct FramebufferWidget : Widget {
    float padding = 0.0;
    float oversampling = 1.0;
};

struct SVGWidget : FramebufferWidget {
    std::string filename;
};

struct SVGKnobWidget : SVGWidget {
    float value = 0.0;
    float minValue = 0.0;
    float maxValue = 1.0;
};

struct MomentarySVGKnobWidget : SVGKnobWidget {
    // No fields, just additional behavior in methods
}

...

addChild(construct<SVGKnobWidget, filename, maxValue>("knob.svg", 2.0))
```

Notice how that is much simpler and easier on the eyes than calling

```
addChild(SVGKnobWidget(Vec(0, 0), Vec(0, 0), 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, "knob.svg", 0.0, 0.0, 2.0));
```

I need to construct pointers because after construction, I immediately transfer ownership to the `addChild` function.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155467/discussion-on-question-by-vortico-construct-object-set-fields-and-return-objec).

Answer (score 0):

C++11 brought uniform initialization to C++. i.e. you can do

```
Foo *foo = new Foo{"Hello", 4};
```

as suggested by user4581301. But this assumes you know the layout of Foo.

You won't find the same kind of syntax as in C# because C++ does not support named parameters.
You can get something close (or even something close to named tuples) using some smart things see http://vitiy.info/named-tuple-for-cplusplus/ or [IOD](https://github.com/matt-42/iod) or plenty of other attempts, but I find the syntax also often annoying, plus some, like IOD, requires that you predeclare named parameters names.

--edit
I now remember that [boost parameters](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html#parameter-enabled-constructors) implements named parameters directly (using the same base concepts as in IOD). Although it requires quite a lot of boiler plate code:

```
myclass y(_index = 12, _name = "sally");
```

Comment: This is a good attempt, but unfortunately I require the parameters to be named, and unnamed parameters to be set to their defaults. Otherwise my constructor calls would look like the following, except 30 times more arguments. `MomentarySVGKnobWidget{Vec(0, 0), Vec(0, 0), 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, "knob.svg", 0.0, 0.0, 2.0};`

Comment: The construct-by-value method doesn't solve the problem either, since I *do* actually need them to be pointers, and it requires roughtly the same amount of code to fill them with values as my original code.

Comment: Ok I did not put foo on the heap for simplicity but this also applies when  you use pointers. regarding default values, just set them when you define the class. I will add an example.

Comment: This is essentially what I am already doing in the first code block of my question.

Comment: The Boost parameters looks the cleanest I've seen so far, of course with the expensive of a lot of internal complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my attempts so far. I've made this a public wiki, so improvements are welcome!

### explicit macros

```
#define construct0(_T, _N) _T *_N = new _T()
#define construct1(_T, _N, _F1, _V1) construct0(_T, _N); _N._F1 = _V1
#define construct2(_T, _N, _F1, _V1, _F2, _V2) construct1(_T, _N, _F1, _V1); _N._F2 = _V2
#define construct3(_T, _N, _F1, _V1, _F2, _V2, _F3, _V3) construct2(_T, _N, _F1, _V1, _F2, _V2); _N._F3 = _V3
#define construct4(_T, _N, _F1, _V1, _F2, _V2, _F3, _V3, _F4, _V4) construct3(_T, _N, _F1, _V1, _F2, _V2, _F3, _V3); _N._F4 = _V4

construct3(Bar, bar, firstName, "John", lastName, "Smith", height, 5.6);
// Expands to
Bar *bar = new Bar(); bar.firstName = "John"; bar.lastName = "Smith"; bar.height = 5.6;
```

Pros: Simple implementation.

Cons: Doesn't return the instantiated value, so can't use `addChild(constructN(...))`, unless you use the GCC Statement Expr extension.
Reusing the same variable names within a scope results in a collision.
Only supports a bounded number of arguments.

I don't think `__VA_ARGS__` can help here.

### member pointer template

```
template<typename T>
T *construct() {
    return new T();
}

template<typename T, typename F, typename V, typename... Args>
T *construct(F f, V v, Args... args) {
    T *o = construct<T>(args...);
    (o->*f) = v;
    return o;
}

construct<Bar>(&Bar::firstName, "John", &Bar::lastName, "Smith", &Bar::height, 5.6);
```

Pros: Returns value, doesn't clutter scope of caller.

Cons: Requires repetitious `&Bar::` before every field name.

### member pointer template + explicit macros

To go further, since we know that identifiers cannot be used in as template parameters, we can let macros do that. We can also count arguments using the GCC ## trick.

```
#define CONSTRUCT_ARGS1(T, f, v) &T::f, v
#define CONSTRUCT_ARGS2(T, f, v, ...) &T::f, v, CONSTRUCT_ARGS1(T, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CONSTRUCT_ARGS3(T, f, v, ...) &T::f, v, CONSTRUCT_ARGS2(T, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CONSTRUCT_ARGS4(T, f, v, ...) &T::f, v, CONSTRUCT_ARGS3(T, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CONSTRUCT_ARGS5(T, f, v, ...) &T::f, v, CONSTRUCT_ARGS4(T, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CONSTRUCT_ARGS6(T, f, v, ...) &T::f, v, CONSTRUCT_ARGS5(T, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CONSTRUCT_ARGS7(T, f, v, ...) &T::f, v, CONSTRUCT_ARGS6(T, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CONSTRUCT_ARGS8(T, f, v, ...) &T::f, v, CONSTRUCT_ARGS7(T, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CONSTRUCT_ARGS9(T, f, v, ...) &T::f, v, CONSTRUCT_ARGS8(T, __VA_ARGS__)
#define ARG20(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18_, _19, _arg, ...) _arg
#define CONSTRUCT_COUNT(...) ARG20(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1)
#define CONSTRUCT_JOIN(count, ...) CONSTRUCT_ARGS ## count(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CONSTRUCT_MACRO(count, ...) CONSTRUCT_JOIN(count, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CONSTRUCT_ARGS(T, ...) CONSTRUCT_MACRO(CONSTRUCT_COUNT(__VA_ARGS__), T, __VA_ARGS__)
#define CONSTRUCT(T, ...) construct<T>(CONSTRUCT_ARGS(T, __VA_ARGS__))


Bar *bar = CONSTRUCT(Bar, x, 4, y, 6);
```

Pros: shortest yet

Cons: Complicated implementation, only works up to N pairs of arguments.

Comment: That's not as bad as I thought it would look. Wandering way out of what I know here, but see if you can apply [varadic templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) to get rid of that number.

Comment: I started doing that 2 minutes ago :) Will modify the second section